# Docker network inspect doesn't show the containers I added to the network with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose` file, where five containers are created. I found the file in [this](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop) repository, and I added a network section for connecting the containers to a docker network I previously created:

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:

networks:
    network1:
        external:
            name: rete1
```

Then, if I type `docker network inspect rete1`, I expect the five containers to be listed, each of them with its own IP. But this is the output I get:

```
{
        "Name": "rete1",
        "Id": "9e5d056f6db828e6d70200f93060b40dda064acd39e6c953f7135b033c2ec45e",
        "Created": "2023-08-10T11:22:44.5849534Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
}
```

I don't know why they don't appear. I have an other `docker.compose` file with other containers, and the same network section at the end, and those containers are successfully added to the network and are shown. Also, if I manually connect the containers to the network with the command `docker network connect rete1 container_id`, it works. But I would like this to be done by the docker-compose.
How can I solve this?

EDIT:
This is the output of `docker network ls`:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                    DRIVER    SCOPE
cb773461d6e5   bridge                  bridge    local
1e724849aa0f   docker-hadoop_default   bridge    local
9e5d056f6db8   rete1                   bridge    local
```

Comment: What is the output of docker network ls? What is the output of docker network inspect network1?

Comment: @TrojanName I had put the output of docker network inspect rete1 in the question. I now edited it to add the output of docker network ls. Running docker network inspect network1 raises an error since there is no network 1

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting. I would have expected docker network inspect network1 to show you what you needed. It looks like its getting confused between the 2 names https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/